# What's the proper frame rate used to convert png files to a video file?

Tags: c#, video, png, aforge, avi

Every 1000 / 60fps milliseconds I take screenshot of a window and save as a png file to a directory then I use [`VideoFileWriter`](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/4ee1742c-44d3-b250-d6aa-90cd2d606611.htm) to create a AVI file from those images. But I don't how frame rate should I use. How do I define it? it's based on `width` or `height` or what else? I tried copy the default frame rate used by [`virtualdub`](http://www.virtualdub.org/), I found it to be 1000.. I tried that rate but the video output was redicuosly slow. Some doc examples use `25`. I don't really know how define that.

```
            const int width = 1920;
            const int height = 1080;
            const int frameRate = 60;

using (var writer = new VideoFileWriter())
            {
                writer.Open("output.avi", width, height, frameRate, VideoCodec.MPEG4);

                foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dest_path, "*.png"))
                {
                    using (var img = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(file))
                    {
                        writer.WriteVideoFrame(img);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Code used to take the screnshots:

```
int i = 0;
        void doRecord()
        {  
            using (var img = GetScreenshot(handle))
            {
                string filename = Path.Combine(dest_path, string.Format("{0}.png", ++i));
                img.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }

        public Bitmap GetScreenshot(IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            RECT rc;

            if (!GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rc))
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            using (var gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();
                bool succeeded = PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, 0);
                gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
                if (!succeeded)
                {
                    gfxBmp.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Gray), new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));
                }
                IntPtr hRgn = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);
                GetWindowRgn(hwnd, hRgn);
                Region region = Region.FromHrgn(hRgn);
                if (!region.IsEmpty(gfxBmp))
                {
                    gfxBmp.ExcludeClip(region);
                    gfxBmp.Clear(Color.Transparent);
                }
                return bmp;
            }
        }
```

I use a Timer to take the screenshot, set up like this:

```
const int fps = 60;
timer1.Interval = 1000 / fps;
timer1.Start();
```

and

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   doRecord();
}
```

Comment: From my understanding, an average monitor runs at 60hz, so take a screenshot ever 1/60 of a second. (is this what you're asking? Also, what do you mean by "define it"?)

Comment: I'm already taking a screenshot at 1/60 of a second. My question is how to define the frame rate passed in the `Open()` method from `VideoFileWriter`. Neither 60 nor 1/60 resulted in "normal" video speed. It was too fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is absolutely no correlation between the shape and/or size of the images you take and the frame rate.**

**Short answer:**

You need to calculate how many screenshots you take every second and make **that** number your frame rate.

**Long Answer:**

I think you are missing on what **frame rate** means, I'll explain:
Human eyes (as most animals) have a property called "[Persistence of Vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_vision)" which basically allows us to interpret the movement of objects as a continuous moving image. This is the concept on which all videos are based.

If you take a bunch photos of a running person and then pass them very fast in front of your eyes you will see the person moving. But it wouldn't necessarily take the same time as it took the actual person. Let's put some numbers in here for context.

You ask your friend Steve to run **1 km** (about half a mile) and you start taking lots of photos of him running. Actually, you take **60 photos each second**. Now the average person runs at 10 km/h so let's use that running speed. It would take Steve 1/10 of an hour to run 1 km, because there are 3600 seconds in 1 hour that would be the same as **360 seconds** or 6 minutes. So you have taken exactly (60*360) **21600 photos**.

Data recap:

- Length run: 1 km
- Speed: 10km/h
- Time: 360 seconds
- Photos per second: 60
- Total photos: 21600

Now, if you wanted to reproduce the photos so it took you the same time to see them as it took Steve to run that distance you would have to display every second the 60 photos you took in *that* second. So you would end up showing 60 photos per second. When you make a video you refer to each of these photos as a "**frame**", therefore you are using a 60 frames/second **frame rate** (or fps).

If you wanted to show a slow-motion video of Steve running you need to lower the amount of fps, going down to 30 fps for half the speed. That would let you with a 12 minute long slow-motion video.

**Please keep in mind that videos usually have over 24 fps, and the lower the fps the more "lagged" the video will look**

*Note: I seriously don't recommend using that method for screen/window recording since it will result in a huge waste of the computer's resources (CPU, RAM and Hard Disk). You should look up some libraries that already do all recording and patching up for you. Unfortunately, I don't have any to recommend.*

Comment: I do record using 60fps (I take a screenshot every 1000 / 60 miliseconds) but when I use 60fps on frame rate passed on `VideoFileWriter.Open()` I get a video output that run hyperfast. 90 imgaes turn into a 3 seconds video

Comment: If you are recording at 60fps, 90 images should make a 1.5seconds video. For videos I recommend using 24fps.
What's important is to play at the same speed that it was recorded, so the video isn't either slowed down or made way faster.

Comment: This is what I'm no understanding: I'm recording as the same fps value I'm recording and still gat a faster video. Check out my code to see if you get what I'm missing... I'm not ignoring your last advice btw, I'll check it out by I've told that this use less memory, once you do the record save to disk and free the resources

Comment: I recommend you change the recording speed to 25 (set the timer interval to 40), and try making the video with that frame rate. Also make sure to measure how long you record, so you can check the output video length.

Comment: set the timer interval to 40 or 1000 / 40?

Comment: Just 40. So it runs every 40miliseconds

Comment: Still, you should use a different thread to tKe each photo. So nothing gets stuck

Answer (score 1):

The human eye can see at a frame rate of 20 fps. A good frame rate could be one bigger than that. But this depends on what you are making the video for. If the video is only for entretaining I recomend 30fps.

Comment: I tried 60fps (same value I use to do the record) but the video output is very short. 90 images turn into a 3s video

Comment: And how many time do you wish that a video with 90 images lasts?

Comment: I think that you are not sampling at 60 fps, can you post you sampling code?